# How to structure controllers and services

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am still relatively new to Ionic and AngularJS and I have the following problem: I created a service in the `controller.js` file and now need this service at loadup (`app.js`) to detect which start page I will route to. How can I export the service from `controller.js` into some other js file so that it will become available in both files `app.js` and `controller.js`.
Thanks,
EL

Comment: Yeah, thanks for downvoting the question without writing a short line why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You import it using angular's dependency injection.

If your controller.js looks something like:

```
angular.module('myModule', [])

.service('myService', ['$scope', 'otherDependency', function($scope, otherDependency){
    //some service code
}]);
```

Then the module you want to use the service in would need to import the module where the service is located and then inject the service itself. So something along the lines of:

```
angular.module('app', ['myModule'])

.controller('appCtrl', ['$scope', 'myService', function($scope, myService){
    //some code using your service
}]);
```

This documentation might help:
AngularJS services - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services
AngularJS dependency injection - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: thanks for the answer, better than just a lousy down-vote and run as seen previously